# How to read array of array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, datatable

my ajax call is returning 3000 records but js is returning 3000 records as 0-99,100-199 so on.... of 3000 records. how can i read all records and bind them into Datatable.

[image]

Also getting this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```js
$.each(response.getResourcesCostings, function(m, n) {
  $('#rescostingbodyid').append('<tr>' + +'<td></td>' + +'<td>' + n.Name + '</td>' + +'<td>' + n.type + '</td>' + +'<td>' + n.location + '</td>' + +'<td>' + n.total + '</td>' + +'</tr>');
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell how you are reading length ? It should be `obj.getResourcesCostings.length`

Comment: I think that this is the way to show you large array prettier in console in fact JS doesn't change your array

Comment: You console is telling you that there are 3000 objects in that array. The console just separates them into groups to make it easier for you to view them.

Comment: Reading it like whats wrong in this code $.each(response.getResourcesCostings, function (m, n) {
                    $('#rescostingbodyid').append('<tr>' +
                        +'<td></td>' +
                        +'<td>' + n.Name + '</td>' +
                        +'<td>' + n.type + '</td>' +
                        +'<td>' + n.location + '</td>' +
                        +'<td>' + n.total + '</td>' +
                        +'</tr>');
                });                         
error :- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: As noted above, the batching shown in the console is something the browser does to make your data easier to manage. The actual response is not batched. With regard to your code, you don't call `length` so that won't be causing the error you describe. Also note that you have too many `+` characters in the string concatenation, which will end up coercing the strings to integers. Your code should look something like this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/k5mt724s/

Comment: Reproducing OPs issue: `var a=[];for (var i=0;i<3000;++i) { a.push(i); } console.log(a);`  - it's *clearly* just how the browser console is displaying the data (put that in a fiddle or SO-snippet with "console in the editor" on).  So the first part is a non-question.

Comment: Second part: *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')* - needs more info.    This is also why SO tells you not to put two questions in one.

Answer (score 1):

Your concatenation has way too many `+` signs: `+ +'<td>'` for example. Strip out the ones you don't need which are causing the code to fail.

If there's an error about `length` it's not coming from the code you posted in your question.

```js
const response = {
  getResourcesCostings: [
    {Name: '1', type: '1', location: '1', total: '1'},
    {Name: '2', type: '2', location: '2', total: '2'}
  ]
};

$.each(response.getResourcesCostings, function(m, n) {
  $('#rescostingbodyid').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + n.Name + '</td>' + '<td>' + n.type + '</td>' + '<td>' + n.location + '</td>' + '<td>' + n.total + '</td>' + '</tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="rescostingbodyid"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's just console optimization. Try JSON.stringify and check what it returns.